# Grant permissions to a file in Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

So, there is a project that I am developing and it's on bitbucket, and inside of it I have a configuration file, so the team should have read-only access to it and it can't be commited by others, but on the other hand I need to be able to update it sometimes, can I grant access to it by users? I think ignoring it would be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it, bitbucket can only restrict the access to branches and not to files.

You could put the configfile in a new branch which is only pushable by you.

Then remove the config file form the other branches and ignore it there.

While building the project you could checkout the configfile from the branch where you put it.